# For continuous surjective map $f: X\to Y$, $f^{-1}(D_j) = \bigcup_{f(C_i) \subseteq D_j} C_i $ ( Connected components )?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: X\to Y$ be a continuous surjective map ( possibly open ) between topological spaces. Let $\{ C_i \}_{i}$ be the components of $X$ and $\{ D_j \}_j$ the components of $Y$. Then for each $j$,

$$f^{-1}(D_j) = \bigcup_{f(C_i) \subseteq D_j} C_i $$
? If so, why?

If this question is true, then we can show that the induced map

$$f^{*} : \{ \operatorname{connected components of} X\} \to \{ \operatorname{connected components of }Y \} , $$

$C \mapsto \operatorname{the unique connected component in Y containing } f(C) $

is surjective.

**EDIT** : My first trial is as follows :

Let $D$ be a connected component of $Y$. Let $E:=f^{-1}(D)$. Let $x\in E$. Let $C_x$ be the connected component of $x$ in $X$. Then $C_x$ is connected and by continuity, $f(C_x)$ is also connected in $Y$. Since $f(C_x)$ and $D$ both contains $f(x)$, $f(C_x) \cup D$ is also connected. By the maximality of connected component, $D = f(C_x) \cup D$ ; i.e., $f(C_x) \subseteq D$. So we have $C_x \subseteq f^{-1}(f(C_x)) \subseteq f^{-1}(D) =:E$. So for every point of $E$, the component of $x$ is also a subset of $E$. **So $E$ is indeed the union of the components of its points**.

From this can we show $f^{-1}(D_j) = \bigcup_{f(C_i) \subseteq D_j} C_i $?
; i.e., can we show $f^{-1}(D_j) = \cup_{x\in f^{-1}(D_j)} C_x = \bigcup_{f(C_i) \subseteq D_j} C_i$ ? The direction "$\subseteq$" is true since we showed that $f(C_x) \subseteq D$ in the above argument. But how about the inverse direction?

Comment: Please show your effort.

Comment: @geetha290krm :  Sorry, this is only form of guess. I haven't attempted to prove it in earnest yet..

Comment: @geetha290krm : O.K. I upload my first trial. Can you review it and give me an advice?

Comment: What you have done is fine.Reverse inclusion is obvious. $f(C_i)\subseteq D_j$ implies $C_i \subseteq f^{-1}(D_j)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm : Yes. I got it. Thank you.

Comment: @geetha290krm :  And also, I think that the surjectivity of $f$ is not used, do you think so too? Used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct and works for each $f : X \to Y$. Surjectivity is not needed.

Let $\mathscr C(X)$ denote the set of components of $X$.

You correctly proved that the preimage $f^{-1}(D)$ of a component $D$ of $Y$ is a union of components of $X$. This means that the set
$$\mathscr C' = \{ C \in \mathscr C(X) \mid C \subset f^{-1}(D) \}$$
has the property that
$$f^{-1}(D) = \bigcup_{C \in \mathscr C'} C .$$
The condition $C \subset f^{-1}(D)$ is equivalent to $f(C) \subset D$ and therefore
$$f^{-1}(D) = \bigcup_{C \in \mathscr C(X) \text{ with } f(C) \subset D} C .$$